# How to Disable Button on CButtonColumn Table

Tags: php, yii, cbuttoncolumn

I want to disable the update button from CGridView Table. I don't know how to do it. Just disable the update button, not delete the function of update. Anybody know how to do it? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you post your CGridView code?

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. Seems a perfectly valid question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'columns' => array(
        // All your columns here
        // ...
        array(
            'template' => '{view}{delete}',
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
```

It's enough :)

**EDIT**: above solution *removes* the button. The following disable it (by removing the link):

```
'columns' => array(
        // All your columns here
        // ...
        array(
            'template' => '{view}{update}{delete}',
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
               'buttons' => array(
                   'update' => array(
                      'url' => ''
                    ),
                ),
         ),
```

Comment: OP wants to *disable* the button, not *remove* it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the 'template' property of your CButtonColumn.
The default value for 'template' is '{update}{view}{delete}'.
So you have to do this:

```
array(
    'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
    'template' => '{view}{delete}',
),
```

Comment: OP wants to *disable* the button, not *remove* it.